# Uniform distribution in a cube

Tags: real-analysis, probability, normal-distribution

I came across the following problem and got stuck.

**Problem:** Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent Unif$(-1,1)$ and $S_n=X_1^2+...+X_n^2$. Let $$A_n=\{x\in \mathbb{R^n}:\sqrt\frac{n}{3}-1<\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}<\sqrt{\frac{n}{3}}+1\}$$Show that for all sufficiently large $n$ the Lebesgue measure of $A_n\cap(-1,1)^n $ is at least $99\%$ of the Lebesgue measure of the cube $(-1,1)^n$.

**Attempt:** I have managed to show that $$\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{\frac{n}{3}}\xrightarrow{d}N(0,\sigma^2=\frac{4}{45})$$ using Slutsky's theorem and some algebra and observed that $$A_n\cap(-1,1)^n=\{x\in (-1,1)^n:\sqrt\frac{n}{3}-1<\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}<\sqrt{\frac{n}{3}}+1\}$$and notice that this is just (if we assume $x_i$'s are uniformed distributed)
$$A_n\cap(-1,1)^n=\{|\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{\frac{n}{3}}|<1\}$$ 
since we have shown that $\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{\frac{n}{3}}\xrightarrow{d}N(0,\sigma^2=\frac{4}{45})$, we have $$P(A_n\cap(-1,1)^n)\rightarrow P(|M|<1)$$where $M$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{4}{45}$. This probability is almost one (0.9999). And I don't know how to go on from here.

Comment: This is a little confusing, since the claim you are trying to show has nothing to do with the sequence of random variables. I assume they are only given as a hint of how to show the result. Now in the last step you just have to use the fact that probabilities in your setting correspond exactly to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Hi Lukas, yes the claim I gave is the hint. Can you explain why the probability is the lebesgue measure? Isn't the Lebesgue measure of the cube $(-1,1)^n$ bigger than 1?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the probability is rescaled Lebesgue measure, and the probability that $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ is in some subset $A_n$ of $(-1,1)^n$ is exactly the ratio of the ($n$-dim.) volume of $A_n$ to the volume of the cube $(-1,1)^n$.

Comment: @LukasGeyer I intuitively get it. But is there a way to show probability is the rescaled Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes, the by definition the distribution of a uniformly distributed random variable on an interval is rescaled Lebesgue measure on that interval. The joint distribution of independent random variables is the product of their distributions, so you get the product of rescaled $1$-dim. Lebesgue measures, which is rescaled $n$-dim. Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @LukasGeyer thanks!! this is very helpful!